# Why does the BlockInput not work for me ? Did i forget anything?

Tags: c#, .net, dll, user32

I want to block the user keyboard input for a short time, but the method does not work.

public partial class NativeMethods
    {

```
    [DllImport("user32.dll", EntryPoint = "BlockInput")]
    [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
    public static extern bool BlockInput([MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)] bool fBlockIt);

}

public class KeyboardBlocker
{

    public static void Block(int span)
    {
        try
        {
            NativeMethods.BlockInput(true);
            Console.WriteLine("should have blocked");
            Thread.Sleep(span);
        }
        finally
        {
            NativeMethods.BlockInput(false);
```

does someone have an idea ? Thanks already

Comment: What exactly does not work? What is the return value you get from `BlockInput`? If it's nonzero you can get the last error using [`GetLastError`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/d852e148-985c-416f-a5a7-27b6914b45d4).

Comment: I dont really get a return value

Answer (score 0):

Apparently the BlockInput function doesn't work in 64 bit. You can try the answer from here:
[Using BlockInput to block keyboard and mouse input](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10005131/using-blockinput-to-block-keyboard-and-mouse-input).

Comment: How is it used ?